# Marcadores Editor Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

Alguém sabe me dizer o que são esses marcadores no editor do eclipse e como tirá-los? Eu não sei como foram aparecer ai, que botão que eu apertei, onde eu cliquei.

[image: Imagem para analisar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Atalho via barra de ferramentas

São espaços e outros caracteres como tab e quebra de linha. Existe um atalho na barra de ferramentas que ativa/desativa essa configuração. O botão está que efetua a ação está em amarelo (o terceiro da esquerda para direta) na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Via preferences

Outra forma de ocultar/visualizar é através menu `window>prefereces`. No three view a esquerda vá em `General>Editors>TextEditor`. Desmarque a opção `show Whitespace characters` como na imagem abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]